# How to order the table by the contents of a column

Tags: postgresql

For school I have to write a query that returns the names of players and the average of their fines (if they had fines otherwise the column should contain 'geen boetes'). The players with 'geen boetes' must come first then I have to order by name, average. The code I have right now is the following:

```
select 
    s.naam, 
    case 
        when avg(bedrag) is null then 'geen boetes' 
        else cast(round(avg(bedrag), 2) as varchar(8)) 
    end as gemiddeld
from spelers s 
left outer join boetes b using (spelersnr)
group by s.spelersnr, s.naam
order by 
    case 
        when gemiddeld like 'geen boetes' then 1 
        else s.naam, gemiddeld 
    end
```

Everything works like it's supposed to except I can't get the order by to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The players with 'geen boetes' must come first then I have to order by name, average

Consider:

```
order by 
    case when gemiddeld = 'geen boetes' then 0 else 1 end, 
    s.naam, 
    gemiddeld
```

This creates three levels of ordering, one for each of your sorting criteria.

As far as concerns Postgres supports column aliases in the `order by` clause. However if the expression is not supported, then you can use the following:

```
order by 
    case when avg(bedrag) is null then 0 else 1 end, 
    s.naam, 
    gemiddeld
```

Comment: I also don't understand why i get this error: 'ERROR:  column "gemiddeld" does not exist
LINE 6: Order by case when gemiddeld = 'geen boetes' then 1 else 0 e...
                           ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 237'

Comment: @Mkay: I added a new solution to my answer.

Comment: When I run the "select version()" command I get this output: PostgreSQL 11.5 (Debian ...)

Comment: Should it be =  ```case when avg(bedrag) is null then 1 else 0 end DESC,``` else the 0 would be before the 1?

Comment: @BlueIris: I think that you are correct. I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *the players with 'geen boetes' must come first* then the `CASE` statement must return a lower value for this case than the `ELSE` part.
You can do it without the CASE statement if you set a `boolean` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
order by 
    avg(bedrag) is not null, 
    s.naam, 
    gemiddeld
```

The expression `avg(bedrag) is not null` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` and since `TRUE > FALSE` all the `null` values will be at the top.